# Is it possible to select the architecture of an execute in Command Prompt?

Tags: command-line, command, command-prompt, execcommand

I have SweetHome 3D.exe that include both x86 and x64 in the same installer.

During the process you have a place where you can select which architecture you want x86 or x64.

My problem came in silent mode where it doesn't ask and install x86 by default. Does anybody have an idea which command I need to add to be in x64. This is working, but it miss me the architecture selection option to add:

```
sweethome3d.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /LANG=french
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a programming, but a software usage problem.

Comment: No, in fact if I will like to install it manually, there will be no problem, but I want to deploy it so I need to find the installation option like /LANG=french for installing it in french. It must exist one for choosing the architecture, but I cannot find it, so I'm telling me maybe other programmers could have an idea.